# Swift Return enum as a string or int depending on case type

Tags: swift, enums, swift4, eureka-forms, decodable

Trying to return a JSON output using Swift's Codable library. I've set up a struct to capture a 'default' value from my JSON. The 'default' value currently has two datatype outputs, string or int. I'm trying to return the string value if the 'default' is string and the int value if it's is an int.

```
struct Settings: Codable {
   let configDefault: IntOrString
   let name: String?
}

enum IntOrString: Codable {
        case integer(Int)
        case string(String)

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            if let int = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
                self = .integer(int)
                return
            }
            if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
                self = .string(string)
                return
            }
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(IntOrString.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Default"))
        }

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            switch self {
            case .integer(let x):
                try container.encode(x)
            case .string(let x):
                try container.encode(x)
            }
        }
    }
```

All this gets decoded into a value defaultValueHolder

```
let defaultValueHolder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Settings.self, from: jsonString)
```

Using Eureka's form library i'm trying to set the table value as the default String or Int returned from the JSON.

```
form +++ Section ("Values")
    // dynamically generates rows
    for values in defaultValueHolder {
            form.last! <<< IntRow() {
                $0.tag = values.name
                $0.title = values.name
                $0.value = values.IntOrString
    }
```

The issue is when trying to add a value to $0.value I cannot cast it as a IntORString enum type and have to return either the int or string depending if a IntRow or TextRow is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `IntRow` and `TextRow` rows will accept only the type that has been defined for their [cells](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Source/Rows/FieldsRow.swift) as below,

```
open class IntCell: _FieldCell<Int>, CellType 
open class TextCell: _FieldCell<String>, CellType
```

this is the reason why you have to extract the value from your `IntOrString` enumeration `type` to assign to the respective `cell's` `row` .

---

**If** you wish to have a row that accepts your type(`IntOrString`) then you have to conform your new type to `Equatable` as eureka `cell`'s accept value types that conform to `Equatable`. Something as below,

```
enum IntOrString: Codable, Equatable
```

Then you should add a new `cell` with `create xib file` as marked to create your custom `view` shown below,

[image]

And then you can update the `IntOrStringTableViewCell` as below,

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class IntOrStringTableViewCell: Cell<IntOrString>, CellType {

    @IBOutlet private weak var valueLabel: UILabel!

    override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        self.updateValue()
    }

    override func update() {
        super.update()
        self.updateValue()
    }

    private func updateValue() {
        guard let value = self.row.value else { return }
        if case .integer(let int) = value {
            self.valueLabel.text = "\(int)"
        } else if case .string(let string) = value {
            self.valueLabel.text = string
        }
    }
}

final class IntOrStringRow: Row<IntOrStringTableViewCell>, RowType {

    required init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)

        self.cellProvider = CellProvider<IntOrStringTableViewCell>(nibName: "IntOrStringTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main)
    }
}
```

Now when you will use this row, you will be able to assign the `IntOrString` value as it is without any casting

```
form +++ Section ("Values")
    // dynamically generates rows
    for values in defaultValueHolder {
         form.last! <<< IntOrStringRow() {
            $0.tag = values.name
            $0.title = values.name
            $0.value = values.IntOrString
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamran for your detailed reply, mostly seems to be working. Except i'm getting a print out of "integer(2)" or "string("test") in the $0.value = values.IntOrString output. Is there a way to just return the string or int value.

Comment: are you able to help with this issue I have above?

Comment: In cell setup you should display the exact value extracted from enum type

Comment: I've started adding "row.value = ..." under the super.setup() in the cell set up but aren't sure what to be setting there. Is this what you meant about the cell set up?

Comment: Yes, connect your label IBOutlet in cell and set text value from row value

Comment: Yes i've done that, the confusing part is what to assign row.value to? You said I said should be returning the exact value extracted from enum type but I don't know what to pass to row.value to generate a "2" or "test" result output.

Comment: @dankthreads I updated the answer. Now you can see how to display the value. Don't forget to connect the `valueLabel` `outlet` in `xib` file

Comment: didn't know you could call a case without a switch statement. Thanks for all your help, managed to get it working. Couldn't have done it without you! Cheers

Comment: Glad it helped!